# rsync with weird files name appended

Tags: rsync, amazon-ec2

I'm doing rsync every 10 minutes via cronjob with a 3g Dongle outside on a field. The rsync will send data to my EC2 server and there I can check the files being sent. But I encounter the destination folder on EC2 has a lot of weird files name shown in the "ls -al". Could you guys help me to understand from the image below? (They looks the same but repeated with extra "characters at the end of the filename")

[image: screenshot]

Comment: these look like some sort of temporary/transient files, perhaps created by your source device while the underlying file (without the added characters at the end) is being built or updated. Does the source have a snapshotting capability (as provided by LVM or btrfs)?

Answer (score 3):

The file names you show look like the temporary files that rsync creates while transferring files (upon successful completion, those are then atomically renamed to the proper name; without the leading dot and trailing six-character extension).

They are normally deleted if the rsync transfer is interrupted cleanly (perhaps because the connection has been lost), but not if rsync somehow gets killed without being given a chance to cleanup.

Perhaps you are encountering a low-memory condition that causes rsync to be killed hard from time to time, or something similar?

Comment: If this is the cause, then maybe running rsync with --partial will allow a re-run to pick up and use these files, which will make it much faster and reduce clutter on the destination.

Comment: To test, set the temporary directory used by `rsync` and see if that is where these files appear. `-T, --temp-dir=DIR` 
http://superuser.com/questions/579001/rsync-does-it-create-a-temp-file-during-transfer

Comment: Personally - I hate rsync. I've seen too many errors of different types when using it to copy files and directories from my MAC to a network share on my router that uses the NFS file system. I've also had to reformat that drive multiple times because rsync created files that were locked and could not be deleted. The reason I kept trying to use rsync vs cp was that it supports exclude filters and it is supposed to be faster. In the end, I wrote a couple of very simple Java classes - Copy.java and CopyJob.java which is a Runnable to support multi-threading and added support for filters...:)